# Move from swing jCombobox to javaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, javafx, combobox

I have an old swing Jcombobox which i used to use like this.

```
baudRatecomboBox = new JComboBox(baudRates);
    baudRatecomboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_baudRateComboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_baudRateComboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_baudRateComboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_baudRateComboBox.gridx = 1;
    gbc_baudRateComboBox.gridy = 3;
    getContentPane().add(baudRatecomboBox, gbc_baudRateComboBox);
String[] baudRates = { "2400", "4800", "9600", "14400", "19200", "38400", "56000", "115200"  };
```

I am re-writing my application using JavaFX and i cant get the comboBox to populate.

This is my FXML

```
<ComboBox id="baudRatecomboBox" fx:id="baudRateComboBox" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="87.0" promptText="Baud" />
```

and this is my Java

```
@FXML
ComboBox baudRateComboBox;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LaserControllerUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Laser Controller");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.getStylesheets().add
         (LaserControllerUI.class.getResource("LaserControllerUI.css").toExternalForm());
        ComboBox<String> baudRateComboBox = new ComboBox();
        baudRateComboBox.getItems().addAll(baudRates);       
        baudRateComboBox.setVisible(true);
```

Why isnt my ComboBox populating?

Comment: You have to use an ´ObservableList´ with JavaFX. Take a look at how [Comboboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm) should be filled

Comment: @NicoT A `ObservableList` is used: The one returned by `ComboBox.getItems()`, which is also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply not adding the rates to the `ComboBox` that is shown on screen.

Since you seem to let `FXMLLoader` create the controller instance, you'll also won't get the `ComboBox` injected to the `Application` object that belongs to the start method.

BTW: In most cases it's a bad idea to use the `Application` class as controller.

In case the set of items in the `ComboBox` is always the same, an `initialize` method of the controller can be used to set the items. Furthermore it's always a good idea to specify the type parameters.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> baudRateComboBox;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // called by FXMLLoader after injecting fields
    baudRateComboBox.getItems().addAll(baudRates);
}
```

---

You could also specify the items directly in the fxml file:

```xml
<ComboBox id="baudRatecomboBox" fx:id="baudRateComboBox" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="87.0" promptText="Baud">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="2400"/> 
            <String fx:value="4800"/> 
            <String fx:value="9600"/> 
            <String fx:value="14400"/> 
            <String fx:value="19200"/> 
            <String fx:value="38400"/> 
            <String fx:value="56000"/> 
            <String fx:value="115200"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

This requires the following imports as processing instructions:

```xml
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
```

---

If you need to pass the `baudRates` array to the controller instead, you can find some solutions here: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your detailed response. I now have it working.  Could you explain what    'ComboBox baudRateComboBox' does in my code then?  it come from a tutorial and i thought that was initialising the combobox?

Comment: @DisplayName The information you've posted isn't enough to be sure, but I recommend reading the description at the end of the following example http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201608100629012634808 which describes how the loading process works. Probably the `baudRateComboBox` field of *some* instance is set by the `FXMLLoader`, but even if it was the field of the instance the `start` method is called for, you're never using the field, but use a local variable instead.